# Effective way to filter on multiple wildcards in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'd like to be able to do

```
gci -filter *.ps1,*.cs,*.sql
```

but that syntax isn't supported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `-Include` which takes an array, instead of `-Filter`. Note that you have to use `*` as the path when using `-Include`:

```
Get-ChildItem * -Include *.ps1,*.cs,*.sql
```

Comment: So for multiple filters, there's really no way to reap the performance advantage of -filter over -include?

Comment: That asterisk is a real gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

With v3, can do `gci -file "*.ps1","*.txt"`

Comment: This too wants the path to be the current directory, but push-location seems to offer a viable workaround. I'm beginning to suspect that -file performs more like -include as opposed to the faster -filter.

Comment: I posted this as a separate qn here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770262/is-get-childitems-new-file-parameter-fast-like-filter-or-slow-like-include

Comment: `-file` is a switch parameter and doesn't accept values! "*.ps1","*.txt" are passed as values for  parameter `-path`. Your command is equivalent to do `gci -path "*.exe","*.xml"` but only excude eventualy directory with name endinf with `.ps1` or `.txt`