# Powershell Get-ChildItem -Filter operates differently to Where clause with same value

Tags: powershell, filter, get-childitem

I have a folder on a server called MyFolder.  There are additional folders called MyFolder.1, MyFolder.2, MyFolder.3 etc.

If I run:

```
gci C:\Sample | ? { $_.Name -like "MyFolder.*" }
```

I get the expected output:

```
    Directory: C:\Sample


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
d----        16/10/2012     12:16            MyFolder.1                                                                
d----        16/10/2012     12:16            MyFolder.2                                                                
d----        16/10/2012     12:16            MyFolder.3
```

However if I run:

```
gci C:\Sample -Filter "MyFolder.*"
```

I get:

```
    Directory: C:\Sample


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
d----        16/10/2012     12:16            MyFolder                                                                  
d----        16/10/2012     12:16            MyFolder.1                                                                
d----        16/10/2012     12:16            MyFolder.2                                                                
d----        16/10/2012     12:16            MyFolder.3
```

I'm confused on how **MyFolder** is included in the output.  I'd expect the output to be the same.

The [online help](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849800.aspx) highlights that the syntax of the filter is based on the provider but I'm unsure what provider is being used in this instance.

Am I missing a fundamental piece of knowledge here?  I've attempted to pass a regex string in to the filter e.g `"MyFolder\.*"` but this simply returns nothing.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

I'm running Powershell version 2.

#### Resolution

Thanks to Roman Kuzmin for pointing out the differences in wildcard matching.  The following gives the expected output:

```
gci C:\Sample\MyFolder.*
```

I'll be using this syntax for ease in the future to reduce noise in code.

Comment: It'd be nice if Microsoft updated the help to explain what -Filter does for the Filesystem Provider, since that's probably the 99.9 and a half % most common case where people are using Get-ChildItem. "Syntax is based on provider" seems a little disingenuous.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `Filter` of FileSystem provider rather uses CMD wildcards than PowerShell wildcards. CMD wildcards are funny and not intuitive in some edge cases, mostly historically. Here is an interesting explanation: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071217-00/?p=24143

Another gotcha to be kept in mind: `ls -Filter *.txt` in fact gets files like `*.txt*` in PowerShell sense, i.e. files with extensions **starting** with *txt*. This may be unexpected and very unpleasant in some scenarios :)

Comment: Thanks for the link and highlighting the wildcard differences.  That's help me resolve the issue (but not in the way I would have expected..)

Comment: Excellent point about `-Filter *.txt` acting like `-Filter *.txt*`. A quibble: The linked article talks about MS-DOS, not CMD (`cmd.exe`). The article goes on to say (emphasis added), "But _some_ quirks of the FCB matching algorithm persist into _Win32_ because they have become idiom.". In other words, the _Windows API_ provides the current behavior, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739503/45375).

Comment: I can vouch for the "unexpected and unpleasant" effect of using -Filter and running a set of SQL scripts against a DB, when one script in the folder was named `filename.sql-skip`.

Answer (score 12):

```
gci C:\Sample -Filter "MyFolder.*"  # here is a filesystem provider; use wildcard `*`,`?`
```

return the same output as (in a cmd.exe shell):

```
dir Myfolder.*
```

If you need a regex this is the way ( `-filter` doesn't accept regex)

```
gci C:\Sample | ? { $_.Name -match '^MyFolder\..*' }
```

like here

```
gci C:\Sample | ? { $_.Name -like "MyFolder.*" }
```

the comparison in the scriptblock is between `[string]` type.

Comment: Thanks Christian, I realised that Filter wouldn't take a regex shortly after re-reading the online doc.

Answer (score 0):

here is some info on filter behavior
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3

MS example.

## When using the -Include parameter, if you don't include an asterisk in the path

## the command returns no output.

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test\ -Include *.txt

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test* -Include *.txt

```
       Directory: C:\Test

       Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
      ----                -------------         ------ ----
      -a----        2/13/2019     08:55             26 anotherfile.txt
      -a----        2/12/2019     15:40         118014 Command.txt
      -ar---        2/12/2019     14:31             27 ReadOnlyFile.txt
```