# What is the FileSystem provider filter syntax?

Tags: powershell, filter, powershell-4.0

`Get-Help Get-ChildItem` displays `-Filter` parameter, with displayed wording "[Specifies a filter in the provider's format or language](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/75cf79bb-4db6-4a67-8c36-3d20754e2190%28v=wps.630%29.aspx)". That language differs between what Powershell calls "providers", and file system is declared as one of them. But I have not found any syntax descriptions on file system provider's filter syntax. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filter syntax supported by the FileSystem provider is sparsely (if it all) documented, probably because there's nothing much to say.

In short, it only supports simple wildcard matching as you know it from Windows XP-era Search:

Any file with an extension:

```
*.*
```

Any file with the `.txt` extension:

```
*.txt
```

Partial wildcard matching:

```
*something*.txt
```

Single-character matching (matches `myfile1.jpg` but not `myfile01.jpg`):

```
myfile?.*
```

Simple character sets (this matches `bear` and `beer`):

```
be[ae]r
```

Simple character ranges (this matches `filea.txt`, `fileb.txt` and `filec.txt`):

```
file[a-c].txt
```

---

**Note**: It *only* supports a single expression per filter, so this is illegal:

```
*.jpg|*.txt
```

Comment: Apparently I'm pretty stupid, I've noticed that `[-Filter]` is an optional and position-based parameter, and I'm accustomed to `dir *.txt` where `*.txt` is actually not path but filter. So there's pretty much nothing but name to be filtered via `Get-ChildItem` prior to getting a `FileInfo` object set. Sad but true.

Comment: Indeed. In case you want multiple filters though, you could use `-Include` - supports same basic wildcard syntax, but accepts an array of string values: `-Include "??id*.jpg","*.txt"`

Comment: I'm also reading that PS5 (or maybe PS1+, but it's hidden) allows `-attributes` for additional filtering. Sadly, no filters by date, and I was really wondering if there's a better way than piping discovered files to `Where-Object`. Thanks again.

Comment: [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12914655/48639) a useful info on the `-Filter` parameter