# Create text file containing a list of all files of a certain type with their filesize

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to create a text file with all filenames of a certain filetype plus the filesize, recursively from a specified directory and all subdirectories.

For example: Listing all `.jpg` files plus their sizes from a huge photo-collection.

I have found several similar questions, but not this specific listing.

One did this with the full path name, but I don't need this and it would become very long.
Another lists all files, but without size.
Another lists all filenames with size, but I can't specify a filetype.

This `PowerShell` command creates the desired list, but I don't know how to limit it to a certain filetype (e.g. `.jpg`)

```
gci -rec|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|%{"$($_.Fullname) $($_.Length)"} >filelist.txt
```

This `batch file` lists all `.jpg`'s, but without showing the filesize.

```
dir /b /s z:\Filme\*.jpg > list1.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (list1.txt) do echo %%~nxA >> list.txt
del list1.txt
```

Could anyone edit one of these? so I get the desired list, or come up with a different solution?

Answer (score 1):

#### Could anyone edit one of these so I get the desired list?

You are almost there with the batch script.

`%~z1` will display the file size (in bytes).

You can also get rid of the temporary file by using a slightly different version of the `for` command.

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /s z:\Filme*.jpg') do (
  if /i "%%~xf" equ ".jpg" echo %%~nxf %%~zf
  ) > list.txt
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- [Dir - list files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [If - Conditionally perform command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Answer (score 1):

You know about the `%%~nxA` modifier, so I'm a bit surprised you didn't notice the `%%~zA` modifier.

To simplify it even more, use a `for /R` loop and don't use a temp file:

```
(for /R %%A in (*.jpg) do echo %%~nxA %%~zA)>list.txt
```

or if you need the full path\name, use `%%~fA` (explicite) or even just `%%A`

Comment: Actually I didn't know about modifiers at all, not even about "for", I only have some VERY basic DOS-knowledge from pre-windows-times (but then I worked with Amigas then...); plus I only learned some assembler, basic and pascal in the 80's.
'

Anyway, I succesfully googled some of that stuff and found "for" and these modifiers, but I'm pretty sure I don't understand the logic of it at all. But this looks promising!

Comment: Remember, you can get help for every command with the `/?` switch (for example `for /?`). You should also bookmark [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt), a great overview of all commands. Or, if you are more the non-masochist type, forget about `cmd` and learn PowerShell instead.

Answer (score 1):

Text output:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\PHOTO' -Filter '*.jp*g' -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer} | 
        Select-Object Name, Length | 
            Out-File -FilePath '.\FileList.txt'
```

CSV output:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\PHOTO' -Filter '*.jp*g' -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer} | 
        Select-Object Name, Length | 
            Export-Csv -Path '.\FileList.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

P.S. I've used `*.jp*g` wildcard that will also match `*.jpeg` files. Unfortunately, `*` [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) matches zero or more symbols, so you can get files like `zzz.jpXXXg` in your list. There are other ways to filter `Get-ChildItem` output that don't suffer from this issue, such as filtering with pipeline and regex but they're slower: `Where-Object {$_.Extension -match '^\.jp[e]{1}g$'}`

Comment: @Compo Example, not requirement. I've improvised a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to not use the `-Filter` parameter, but the `-Include` instead where the wildcard pattern works as expected, like this:

**PowerShell version 3.0 and up**

```
Get-ChildItem 'z:\Filme' -File -Include '*.jpg' -Recurse | 
    Select FullName, Length | 
    Export-Csv '.\FileList.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

**PowerShell version below 3.0**

```
Get-ChildItem 'z:\Filme' -Include '*.jpg' -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { !$_.PsIsContainer} | 
    Select FullName, Length | 
    Export-Csv '.\FileList.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

Note that `-Include` only works if you also specify `-Recurse` or if you have the path end in `\*` like in `Get-Childitem 'z:\Filme\*'`.
Also, `-Filter` works faster than `-Include` (or `-Exclude`) parameters. 
As stated in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1#parameters):

*"Filters are more efficient than other parameters, because the provider applies them when the cmdlet gets the objects. Otherwise, PowerShell filters the objects after they are retrieved."*

Comment: @user1016274 Thanks for fixing the typos!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Get-ChildItem "yourdir" -File -Filter '*.jpg' -Recurse | 
    Select FullName, Length | 
        Export-Csv '.\FileList.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: `-Filter *.jpg` acts like `*.jpg*` which means that your code to list names and sizes for files with a `.jpg` extension, is matching, _unlikely but possible_, extensions `.jpong` and `.JPG-bak` too.

Comment: @Compo `-Filter *.jpg acts like *.jpg*` - no, it doesn't. Proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JRBB.png

Comment: [Counter argument](https://imgur.com/mtGskeS), also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12914655)!

Comment: @Compo Looks like it's OS-specific: [Provider-specific-Filter](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShellTraps/tree/master/Basic/Provider-specific-Filter): `NOTE: Windows 10 seems to work differently, in a more expected way.`

Comment: I understand that, however as the OP was using PowerShell pre v3.0 syntax in their example, `?{!$_.PSIsContainer}`, assuming `Windows 10` or I suppose the version of `PowerShell` installed is a little over optimistic.

Comment: @Compo...  It increases readability. That's all. The code still does the same. I would like to recommend it for your code as well.  ;-)  If you like to read something about [The PowerShell Best Practices and Style Guide](https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle) ... It is also recommended NOT to use abreviations and aliasses!

Comment: @Compo, I did not alter anything you posted. The changes I made to the other posts has been accepted by the original posters. So what's your point? To follow well known best practice and style guides for a programming language is not about aesthetics or opinion. I promise I will keep in mind that you don't like to get your badly formatted code improved.  ;-)

Comment: @Compo, it would make your code easier readable for humans. That's all. Period. It wouldn't affect the function. Is it something bad to be easier readable for humans? I thought this site is for humans!?

Answer (score 0):

I have never looked into the layout from the `Where` command, but if it does not alter between languages/locales, *or technically if your layout is not too dissimilar to that of my test system*, you could do it on your machine like this:

From the Command Prompt:

```
(For /F "Tokens=1,3*" %A In ('Where/T /R . *.jpg 2^>Nul')Do @Echo("%C","%A")>"list.txt"
```

From a batch file:

```
@(For /F "Tokens=1,3*" %%A In ('Where/T /R . *.jpg 2^>Nul')Do @Echo("%%C","%%A")>"list.txt"
```

Obviously if the layout from your `Where` command output differs there's still a possibility to adjust the `Tokens` and/or include delimiters to suit your target system.

In the examples above, I've used **`.`** to represent the current directory, you could of course change that to another relative path, e.g. `..\Pictures`, or full path, e.g. `C:\Users\Patrick\Pictures` as necessary.

---

And a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) option:

```
Ls -Filt '*.jpg' -Fo -Rec -EA SilentlyContinue|?{!$_.PSIsContainer -And $_.Extension -Eq '.jpg'}|Select FullName,Length|ConvertTo-CSV -NoT|Select -Skip 1|SC '.\list.txt'
```

This will also include e.g. system and hidden files, will not include files with extensions other than `.jpg` and will not include an unrequested header with that listing.