# Powershell script CPU usage high

Tags: windows, performance, powershell, server

I've got a simple script that looks for a file across a bunch of servers. Issue is that on each server it is pegging CPU and causing issues for production workloads. How can I get this script to not DDoS my machines?!

```
Start-transcript C:\tools\Querylog.txt

$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*windows*server*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties OperatingSystem

Invoke-command -ComputerName $Server-ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Root -Recurse -Force -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*somefile-readme*' } |Out-File -FilePath <filePath>\results.txt -Append}

Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: [1] use the `-Filter` for your G-Ci call instead of grabbing EVERYTHING and then filtering with the `Where-Object` call. [2] you may want to look at the `CIM_DataFile` class - it can find any type of file and is somewhat faster than G-CI. [3] try using robocopy - it is MUCH faster than G-CI.

Comment: `-Filter` alone can make a difference of multiple minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use the `-Filter` option with `Get-ChildItem`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12914655/584676), it should be much more performant than returning all objects and filtering with `Where-Object`.

---

Also, not related to your CPU issue but in how you are crafting your `Get-ADComputer` call, [you should use a `String`, not a `ScriptBlock`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218670/how-to-effectively-use-the-filter-parameter-on-active-directory-cmdlets/51218671#51218671) for the `-Filter` arguments on these cmdlets. From that answer:

> `-Filter` doesn't support `ScriptBlocks`, but they **Kind of Work Sometimes™** because they get ToString'd before getting evaluated. They will technically work if you use simple variable expansion like `$_` or `$emailAddress`, but it will eventually cause you a headache, especially if you try to access an object property (like above) because it simply won't work. Use a string filter every time, and if you need to use an object property as a filter parameter, use [Variable Substitution](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-01-13-powershell-variable-substitution-in-strings/#variable-substitution) or [Command Substitution](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-01-13-powershell-variable-substitution-in-strings/#command-substitution).

Comment: I'll give it a go. I received this script from someone else. I'm not very good with PS... seems to me the script is incomplete though. I'm not able to follow its logic.

Comment: I added a link to another answer where the `-Filter` parameter on `Get-ChildItem` is explained in more detail, along with a link to an MS blog post on the filtering options. There are some other good answers on that page as well that may help you.