# How to display only the double extension file instead of all files?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a script that will display files with double extensions, but the problem is that it displays all the files instead of just the ones with the double extension.  Is there a way of doing this?

here is what i have:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\User\Downloads -filter *.txt.* -Recurse
```

This display all the txt files as well as the ones with an extra .txt (test.txt.txt)  So I am trying to just display the double txt extension.

Hope i have explained this properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for an official documentation as there is nothing concrete on the MSDN for `Get-ChildItem` on this. [mklement0 links to an answer that covers this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739503/45375) If you put this into the path you would get the results you are looking for.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\User\Downloads\*.txt.*"
```

That *might* be slower than `-Filter` but it would get you what you wanted and does work recursively (in PowerShell v3.0+). That only covers you for txt files though. If you wanted to file *all* doubled/repeated extension files you could post process the `Get-ChildItem` with a `where` clause.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\User\Downloads" -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object{$_.Extension -and $_.BaseName -match "$([regex]::Escape($_.Extension))$"}
```

The clause matches for files that

1. Have an extension and
2. The names (without extension) have that same extension on the end. `$_.Extension` will return ".txt" for example. `-match` supports regex so we need to escape that period to ensure no false positives.

The `-File` parameter is definitely part of PS v3.0. That will return all files that have a double extension at the end of their fullnames. The trailing `$` is not interpreted by PowerShell as anything special since it does not have any characters following it that would be confused as a variable. You could escape `` `$ ``, but that would be only to serve as a reminder of what the dollar sign is for. The presence of the backtick here does not change the outcome in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

**Use `-Include`** rather than `-Filter`, which makes the wildcard pattern work as intended:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\User\Downloads -Recurse -Include *.txt.*
```

<sup>Note: This matches files that have `.txt.` *anywhere in the filename*, including `foo.txt.csv` or "triple extensions" files such as `foo.txt.txt.txt`.

`*.txt.txt` would yield only filenames that *end in* `.txt.txt`, which would still include triple-or-more `.txt`-extension filenames.

Note that `*.txt.txt` would work with `-Filter` too.</sup>

While the **`-Filter` parameter** has one major advantage - it makes the underlying filesystem provider perform filtering *at the source* which makes it **much faster** - it has **limitations and pitfalls**:

- The wildcard pattern language is *more limited* than PowerShell's own, with legacy quirks - see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739503/45375) for background information.

  - In essence, only `*` and `?` are supported (not also character set/range expressions such as `[0-9]`), and `.*` or just `.` *at the end* of a pattern match the *empty string* too (which is what you experienced).
  - In *Windows PowerShell* (no longer a problem in PowerShell [Core] 6+), matching is unexpectedly also performed against the normally hidden *short* (8.3) filenames, which means that something like `*.xls` unexpectedly behaves like `*.xls*` and also matches `.xlsx` files, for instance.
- You can only pass a *single* wildcard pattern to `-Filter`, whereas `-Include` supports multiple.

---

On a side note, **`-Include` and `-Exclude` have their quirks too**. Here, `-Include` works as intended due to `-Recurse`; **without `-Recurse`, you'd have to make your `-Path` value end in `\*` to make it work** - see [GitHub issue #3304](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3304).

Alternatively, if you need only a *single* wildcard pattern, you can get away with directly appending that pattern to the path - `C:\Users\User\Downloads\*.txt.*` - as demonstrated in [Matt's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42424963/45375).
However, the caveat is that with `-Recurse` this only works as intended in PSv3 or above;
PSv2, by contrast, applies the pattern only to the *immediate children* (which was arguably the more sensible behavior).

---

On a related but distinct note, [TessellatingHeckler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler) has discovered an oddity when specifying *literal* paths that end in `.` chars. (present since at least PSv2 and still as of PSv5.1):

```
PS> Get-Item -LiteralPath c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe... | Format-List Name, Extension

Name      : cmd.exe...
Extension : .exe
```

Note how (a) `cmd.exe` was still matched, despite the extraneous trailing `.` chars., and (b) the `.Name` property reflects those `.` chars. - even though neither `.Extension` nor `.FullName` do.

The issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3197), but since the the cause is the legacy-bound behavior of the underlying `GetFileAttributes` native Windows API function, this issue will not be resolved in PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for the linked question. That is what I could never find. Never even occurred to look here for it.

Comment: @Matt: Glad to hear it's helpful; it is unfortunate that the [`Get-ChildItem` help topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) is so tight-lipped about the subject, with no link to additional information: "The syntax of the filter, including the use of wildcards, depends on the provider."

Answer (score 0):

Files don't really have double extensions, they have one extension and you have files with dots in the name. e.g. `Appartment 1.04 in block ten - building report.txt` will come out in your report as a double extension called *.04 in block ten - building report.txt*.

So:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\User\Downloads -Recurse | Where {$_.Extension -eq '.txt' -and $_.BaseName -match '\.' }
```

Will get all files and filter .txt extensions and names with dots in them.