# Having trouble assigning the output of Get-ChildItem to a variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, wildcard, glob, get-childitem

I'm writing a script for work - it is supposed to loop through a multi-lined csv file, and separate each row into its own separate csv. The issue I'm having is with this line:

```
$csvfile = Get-ChildItem -Path $baseDir* -Include *.csv
```

Here's a snippet of the section where this line is:

```
#  get script directory and add it to a variable
$baseDir = $PSScriptRoot
# Write-Host $baseDir

#  get a list of csv file names
    
$csvfile = Get-ChildItem -Path $baseDir* -Include *.csv
```

The problem is, the variable $csvfile remains empty, so nothing really happens in my script. When I change '$basedir' in the line with the actual path, it works. Through debugging, I know $basedir has a value in it (and it's correct - the actual path), so I'm not sure why the Get-ChildItem will work with the path, but not the variable.

Hope this explanation makes sense - I am the furthest thing from a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

**Change `$baseDir*` to `$baseDir\*`**, given that you want the `-Include` filter to apply to the *child items* (files and subdirectories) of `$baseDir`

- By contrast, `$baseDir*` just looks for `$baseDir` *itself, as well as any similarly named sibling directories*, namely those whose name *starts with* the same name as that of the one identified by `$baseDir`; the resulting directories are reported *as themselves*, rather than having their child items enumerated, so the `-Include` pattern is matched against *their* names, which won't work.

Therefore:

```powershell
$csvfile = Get-ChildItem -Path $baseDir\* -Include *.csv
```

Note that **use of `-Include` indeed requires `\*` at the end of the input path, which is unfortunate**, given that `Get-ChildItem $baseDir` by itself is enough to enumerate the child items of a directory; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375) explains the **counterintuitive behavior of the `-Include` and `-Exclude` parameters**.

---

The **simpler - and also faster - alternative** is to use the `-Filter` parameter, which **doesn't require the trailing `\*`**:

```powershell
$csvfile = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $baseDir -Filter *.csv
```

Note that, unlike with `-Include`, the **wildcard expressions supported by `-Filter` are *not* [*PowerShell*'s wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)**, and have legacy quirks; *typically*, that won't matter, but on occasion it does - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42425413/45375).

Comment: The ```\```, qualifies that one is a true qualified path name the other is a name variant of the pathname provided. See also the details that parameter binding has its particulars. [See details via this cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command?view=powershell-7.2).  If you did the same in cmd.exe ```dir D:\temp*``` vs ```dir D:\Temp\*``` the results would be the same; meaning one does not provide results, and the other does, because one is a name variant for the pathname, and the other is the content in a qualified pathname provided