# Powershell Folder List Filter

Tags: powershell, sorting, date, chronological

I have a folder and inside has a list of subfolders/files
Folders

- 2022
- 20221101
- 20221103
- 20221107
- 20221108
- test123
- results
- test.txt

Using Powershell

1. How do get the list of folders that are dates.
2. How do I get the second latest folder (20221107).

This is what I was able to come with so far:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\code\Test" -Filter "2022*" | Sort-Object Name -Descending
```

Comment: is `2022` considered a date for you, or just the `2022MMdd` ones?

Comment: 2022MMdd only. Ignore everything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`TryParseExact` method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact) from [`DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) to parse the folders names and avoid any type of error, this can be combined with [`Sort-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) and [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) to get the 2nd latest. I have added `-Directory` to output only folders. Also changed your filter to `-Filter "2022????"` to ensure you're matching folders that start with `2022` and are followed by 4 characters.

```bash
$ref = [ref] [datetime]::new(0)

Get-ChildItem "C:\code\Test" -Filter "2022????" -Directory | Sort-Object {
    $result = [datetime]::TryParseExact(
        $_.Name,
        'yyyyMMdd',
        [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture,
        [Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::AssumeLocal,
        $ref
    )
    if($result) { $ref.Value }
} -Descending | Select-Object -Index 1
```

If you want to ensure you're matching folders with a date format (because `-Filter` may be too permissive), you can pipe to `Where-Object` for additional filtering via regex:

```bash
$ref = [ref] [datetime]::new(0)

Get-ChildItem "C:\code\Test" -Filter "2022????" -Directory |
    Where-Object Name -Match '^2022\d{4}$' | Sort-Object {
        # rest of the code here
    } -Descending | Select-Object -Index 1
```

Comment: Nice, though you can avoid the `-Filter` quirks with `-Include` (which then requires you to end the path in `\*`).

Comment: @mklement0 good point tho I'll never understand how `-Include` and `-Exclude` work

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon :) yeah, `-Include` and `-Exclude` are a mess; the rule of thumb is: with `-Recurse`, they mostly work as expected; without `-Recurse`, it's best to use `Get-Item`, and append `\*` to the `-Path` argument.

Comment: (Case in point: I just realized that combining `Get-ChildItem -Directory` with `-Include` does _not_ work, even with `\*`; sigh....)

Comment: @mklement0 see, thats why I don't care to learn how they work. too unreliable for me :P `-Filter "2022????"` does work fine for folders, not sure why it didn't for OP based on his comments

Comment: Can only imagine it bugs out attempting to translate the wildcard patterns into a RegEx one in the "background".

Comment: @AbrahamZinala `-Filter` is passed to the `.Enumerate*` methods from `DirectoryInfo` behind the scenes, and it only understands `*` and `?` as wildcard characters

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I was referring to maybe a mess-up on the engine itself seeing as all wildcard patterns (*in PowerShell*) are translated internally into it's corresponding regular expression under the hood. Basically why `??????` wasn't working lol

Comment: Understood, @Santiago - memorizing all the rules and exceptions is a pain. I too didn't see the problem with `-Filter` and `?` with directories _in this case_, but note it's still too permissive in general; e.g, `Get-ChildItem ~ -Filter Deskto???` still matches `Desktop`.

Answer (score 4):

To provide an alternative to [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74366715/45375):

Since the timestamps that your folder names represent sort *lexically* in a way that is equivalent to their *chronological* sorting, you may not need to convert them to `[datetime]` instances, and can sort them as-is.

```bash
Get-Item C:\code\Test\* -Include 2022???? |
  Sort-Object Name -Descending |
  Select-Object -Index 1
```

Note the use of `-Include` instead of `-Filter` (which in turn necessitates ending the `-Path` argument with `\*` and using `Get-Item` instead of `Get-ChildItem`), because the `-Filter` parameter has legacy quirks that prevent character-exact matching with multiple `?` wildcards - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42425413/45375) for background information.

- Unfortunately, as this solution and the linked answer shows, making `-Include` (and `-Exclude`) work as intended is tricky as of PowerShell 7.2.x, and requires memorizing non-intuitive rules.

On the plus side, `-Include`, which (unlike `-Filter`) uses *PowerShell*'s [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), would also allow you to create a more specific pattern, such as `-Include 2020[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]` (which still isn't strict enough to rule out *invalid* digit combinations, however).