# Using Remove-Item cmdlet but excluding sub-directory

Tags: powershell

I want to remove the following files from the source, however in the source there is a sub-directory that contains files with similar names. When I run the following command it is deleting files in the sub-directory with similar file name. Is there a way to just delete the files from the source and not the sub-directory?

Example: `test_1_file`, `test_2_file`, `test_3_file` exists in each directory, `TestFolder` and `TestFolder/sub`

```
$source = testfolder 
remove-item -Path $source -filter test_*_file -recurse -force
```

Comment: Omit `-recurse`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's usually easiest to pipe the output of `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet into `Remove-Item`. You then can use the better filtering of `Get-ChildItem` as I think `-Recurse` in `Remove-Item` has some issues. You can even use `Where-Object` to further filter before passing to `Remove-Item`

```
$source = testfolder
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter test_*_file -Recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.Fullname -notlike "$source\sub\*"} |
    Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Looks like this was still removing test_*_file from "$source/sub/*"

Comment: @mike Verify that you slashes are facing the correct direction. If it's Windows they should be backslashes. Because the issue will be the matching in the `Where-Object` filter. I used the `/` to match your path, but I have edited the answer since you had issues.

Answer (score 2):

If the files to delete:

- are all located *directly* in `$source`
- and no other files / directories must be deleted:

```
Remove-Item -Path $source/test_*_file -Force
```

No need for `-Recurse` (as @Bill_Stewart notes).

Note: For conceptual clarity I've appended the wildcard pattern (`test_*_file`) directly to the `$source` path.
Using a wildcard expression *separately* with `-Filter` is generally faster (probably won't matter here), but it has its [quirks and pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739503/45375).