# Where to apply -ErrorAction on a .Net call?

Tags: .net, powershell, file, permission-denied, enumerate

This works to count *.jpg files.

```
PS C:\> @([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('C:\Users\Public\Pictures', '*.jpg', 'AllDirectories')).Count
8
```

How can an `-ErrorAction Continue` be applied to this?

```
PS C:\> @([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('C:\Users', '*.jpg', 'AllDirectories')).Count
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Access to the path 'C:\Users\Administrator' is denied..
At line:1 char:1
+ @([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('C:\Users', '*.jpg', 'AllDire ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: ...don't use a .NET call? `(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Public\Pictures" -Recurse -File -Filter "*.pdf" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count`

Comment: Use `try{...} catch{...}`

Comment: @Theo That will catch the exception, but won't continue the operation.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You're right there, but without having permissions on the path you will not get a correct count anyway if any, so this question is rather pointless I think..

Comment: @Theo: There's still value in obtaining _all_ files that are _accessible_ while ignoring those that aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. Unless you want to implement directory traversal yourself you're probably stuck with something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users' -Filter '*.jpg' -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54219953/45375) shows a ***workaround* using `Get-ChildItem`**, which is **necessary** when using the full, Windows-only ***.NET Framework*** (FullCLR), on which ***Windows PowerShell*** is built.

By contrast, ***.NET Core* v2.1+** - on which **PowerShell *Core*** is built - *does* offer a solution:

```
@([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles(
  'C:\Users',
  '*.jpg', 
  [System.IO.EnumerationOptions] @{ 
    IgnoreInaccessible = $true
    RecurseSubDirectories = $true
  }
)).Count
```

Note that this is the equivalent of `-ErrorAction Ignore`, not `Continue` (or `SilentlyContinue`), in that inaccessible directories are *quietly ignored*, with no way to examine *which* of them were inaccessible afterwards.

The solution above is based on [this `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles()` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netcore-2.2#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_EnumerationOptions_), which offers a [`System.IO.EnumerationOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions?view=netcore-2.2) parameter.

Comment: So without jumping to PowerShell Core there's no other way around it to use the `[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles` as it's much faster than `Get-ChildItem`? I saw a C# method to get around it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986333/8262102). I wonder if it's possible for that to work in PS.

Comment: @Ste, I suspect that ad-hoc-compiling such C# code with `Add-Type` may be your only option.

Comment: I was thinking that was the only option. Thanks for the info. I don't know how to incorporate that but I think I might get away without the need atm. But if the need arises I'll ask a new Q on how to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers work around the issue. They donnot appy the error action.

To realy catch the error action in the .net call, I'm using the $ErrorActionPreference variable in Windows PowerShell, as descirbed in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/handling-errors-the-powershell-way/:

```
# Store $ErrorActionPreference
$OldErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
# Set $ErrorActionPreference for .net action
# see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/handling-errors-the-powershell-way/ for other values
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
# .net call
@([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('C:\Users\Public\Pictures', '*.jpg', 'AllDirectories')).Count
# restore origional $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = $OldErrorActionPreference
```

Comment: This fails and doesn't gather the subsequent files after it encounters a folder it cannot access.