# cmd count files effciently, stop count if over 100

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

**Is there a way to count number of files in a folder then stop if over a limit (for efficiency), say 100?**

I am not a programmer, I believe this has to do with looping & controlling the iterations. I have tried some various command & am not figuring it out. Thanks in advance :)

Backstory: I have an interactive batch file that recursively lists files in a folder. I'd love if I could warn user if there is a large number of files before listing the files. I found a command to count the number of files, catch-22 it likely takes as long to count the files as it does to list them; both (counting & its efficiency) are covered here:
[Efficiently counting files in directory and subfolders with specific name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215968/efficiently-counting-files-in-directory-and-subfolders-with-specific-name)

File list interactive script if it helps for context:

```bash
REM https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/196158/how-to-create-a-text-file-list-of-the-contents-of-a-folder
REM this is a comment line, technically called a REM(ark) line
REM @echo off tells command-prompt not to show commands & directory location (what you normally see when opening cmd), the @ symbol says to not show that command itself. We clear the screen (cls) so it doesn't show THIS remark text or any errors about being run from a UNC location. The two && says that if the 1st command is successful do the 2nd one
REM %1 is a placeholder/variable for the filename of whatever is dropped-on the batch. If we had just put echo %1 & no file was specified it would be like putting echo by itself turning echo back on. IF checks whether the variable is blank/not-given & does a blank line if so; ELSE gets processed if variable wasn't blank (display the file path+name in our situation). The brackets are needed if there is a space in the file path/name. The empty brackets indicate a blank string (similar to ""). The parenthesis tells IF to process only things inside it, without it the program will think you want to run "echo. ELSE echo %1", basically echo the rest of the line
REM %~dp0 is the location of THIS batch file (%0=file path including the filename, dp tells it to cut that out [DrivePath only]), %1 is the variable holding the filename & path
@echo off && cls
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Directory contents I will list in Notepad:
IF [%1]==[] (echo [%~dp0]) ELSE (echo [%1])
echo.
echo You can choose another location by dragging it onto this batch file or copying this batch file to it
echo #4 is the only way to get JUST filenames. Sadly DIR command can't show just filenames AND date else it has headers and summary, try #3 for that
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM cmd/batch files do not support UNC paths (\\acme.com\SharedFolder) natively-kb156276. PUSHD is the workaround, it maps UNC to a drive letter, then CHANGES-MOVES to that path, POPD reverts it (removes network drive)-kb317379
IF [%1]==[] (pushd %~dp0) ELSE (pushd %1)
echo.
 
REM declare then fill variable to file path we will store output; %temp is SYSTEM variable going to C:\Users\UserWhoRanScript\AppData\Local\Temp; parenthesis in case it has a space in path which causes errors
set ListFileLog="%temp%\FileListing.txt"
 
REM CHOICE prompts users; /C list of choices; /M message before prompt
CHOICE /C 123456 /M "Choose what to list: 1)All files; 2)All files-newest first (no folder dates); 3)All files-all dates (Create+Modify); 4)All files-no date or sizes; 5)Executables/compressed (exe, msi, zip, 7z, rar); 6)Media files"
REM IF ERRRORLEVEL by itself has a weird oddity so this format checks it exactly as user enters then jumps to that section of the script
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "1" GOTO ListAll
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "2" GOTO ListAllNewestFirst
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "3" GOTO ListAll-EveryDate
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "4" GOTO ListAllNoDatesSizes
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "5" GOTO ListExe
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "6" GOTO ListMedia
 
:ListAll
REM S=subdirectory files (recursive) we then redirect > that output to our text file so it stays open for user when cmd window closes. > wipes logfile contents whereas >> appends to existing logfile contents
dir /s > %ListFileLog%
GOTO ExitProc
 
:ListAllNewestFirst
REM /a attributes -d means don't show directories (doesn't show folder modify date or the period(.) folders); /o order by [d]ate - is to reverse so newest first; /t time-date to show ([c]reation, last [a]ccess, last [w]ritten)
dir /a:-d /o:-d /s > %ListFileLog%
GOTO ExitProc
 
:ListAll-EveryDate
REM shorthand: powershell ls^|fl
REM there is no way to show creation, modify, and access dates with cmd dir so using powershell. ^carat is because cmd will interpret that as you giving another command so fails
powershell.exe Get-ChildItem -Recurse ^| Select-Object FullName,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,LastAccessTime > %ListFileLog%
GOTO ExitProc
 
:ListAllNoDatesSizes
REM B=bare no dates or file sizes
dir /s /b > %ListFileLog%
GOTO ExitProc
 
:ListExe
REM show only files with these extensions, S and B switches/parameters detailed above
dir /s /b *.exe *.msi *.zip *.7z *.rar > %ListFileLog%
GOTO ExitProc
 
:ListMedia
dir /s /b *.mp3 *.wma *.aac *.m4a *.wav *.mpg *.mp4 *.avi > %ListFileLog%
GOTO ExitProc
 
:ExitProc
popd && cls
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ !!DONE!! ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo.
echo You should see output in Notepad, close Notepad ^& this window will close with it
start /w notepad %ListFileLog%
del %ListFileLog%
exit
```

Comment: Please be aware that the tests used in your link appear to have all been performed from PowerShell itself. If you try to run `powershell.exe` from a batch file, just doing so would add a not insignificant delay to your process. This may mean that running `PowerShell` may only be worthwhile if you have a very large number of matching files and/or subdirectory tree.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple enough if you're wanting to cap the count at 100 and then ask the user to continue.  Consider this as an option.  (Multiple REM lines to help explain what's going on)

```cmd
:PreCountDir [Strings to search, separated by space]
REM setlocal enabledelayedexpansion saves a little headache with 
REM trying to manipulate/read variables in a for loop so there is
REM less work involved thus making it cleaner / easier to read.
REM Note - the "%" for variable designations are changed to "!" -
REM This tells the CMD interpreter while using enabledelayedexpansion
REM to expand this variable now, and confirm the value it contains
REM at the time of access.  For every setlocal you should also use an
REM endlocal you are setting it at a module level vs globally.
REM enableextensions required to pass arguments for Call Line.
REM %~1 takes the string specified and strips any wrapping quotes so 
REM it doesn't break the 'Dir' command.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

REM "Undefines" preCount variable (makes it "nothing")
set "preCount="
REM For Loop iterates across the output of the Dir command - note - 
REM it's most accurate to keep /b and /s since all options are
REM recursing in the other routines and you do not have to stress
REM about the extra "fluff" from the standard Dir command.
REM Sending stdOut to nul, as well as stdErr to keep output clean.
REM (stdErr to nul = 2^>nul)
For /f "Delims" %%D in ('Dir /s /b %~1 ^>nul 2^>nul') do (
  REM incrementing preCount by 1 per file in the output
  set /a "preCount+=1"
  if "!preCount!" GEQ "100" (
    REM Prompting user whether to continue or not.
    Choice /c 12 /M "The count of files for this directory so far is at or higher than 100.  Do you wish to continue?  [1. Yes] [2. No]
    If "!Errorlevel!"=="1" endlocal && Goto :EOF
    If "!Errorlevel!"=="2" Exit   
  )
)
REM This Goto :EOF may not be required, but will prevent the 
REM code from moving to the ExitProc when there's a problem 
REM encountered, or the count is less than 100.  Otherwise
REM the ExitProc code will execute.
Goto :EOF
```

Then, from every routine you are looking to confirm, you simply supply the search strings as an argument to the `PreCountDir` routine.  You can place the :PreCountDir anywhere in the file.

```cmd
REM See the updated Routines with the PreCountDir call line
:ListAll
REM S=subdirectory files (recursive) we then redirect > that output to our text file so it stays open for user when cmd window closes. > wipes logfile contents whereas >> appends to existing logfile contents
REM No args since the search below doesn't care.
Call :PreCountDir ""
dir /s > %ListFileLog%
GOTO ExitProc
 
:ListAllNewestFirst
REM /a attributes -d means don't show directories (doesn't show folder modify date or the period(.) folders); /o order by [d]ate - is to reverse so newest first; /t time-date to show ([c]reation, last [a]ccess, last [w]ritten)

REM passing the check to only look for non-directories to the PreCountDir routine
REM (/a:-d) - '/o:-d' is for date specifics which don't matter on a count if no

Call :PreCountDir "/a:-d"

dir /a:-d /o:-d /s > %ListFileLog%
GOTO ExitProc
 
:ListAll-EveryDate
REM Calling PreCountDir with no arguments since we don't care about file filtering and all files will be accessed with the Powershell command.
Call :PreCountDir ""

REM shorthand: powershell ls^|fl
REM there is no way to show creation, modify, and access dates with cmd dir so using powershell. ^carat is because cmd will interpret that as you giving another command so fails
powershell.exe Get-ChildItem -Recurse ^| Select-Object FullName,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,LastAccessTime > %ListFileLog%
GOTO ExitProc
 
:ListAllNoDatesSizes
REM Calling PreCountDir with no args to match the end search.
Call :PreCountDir ""
REM B=bare no dates or file sizes
dir /s /b > %ListFileLog%
GOTO ExitProc
 
:ListExe
REM Calling PreCountDir to look for the same filetypes
Call :PreCountDir "*.exe *.msi *.zip *.7z *.rar"

REM show only files with these extensions, S and B switches/parameters detailed above
dir /s /b *.exe *.msi *.zip *.7z *.rar > %ListFileLog%
GOTO ExitProc
 
:ListMedia
REM Calling PreCountDir to search for extensions below and count:
Call :PreCountDir "*.mp3 *.wma *.aac *.m4a *.wav *.mpg *.mp4 *.avi"

dir /s /b *.mp3 *.wma *.aac *.m4a *.wav *.mpg *.mp4 *.avi > %ListFileLog%
GOTO ExitProc

REM <-----Placing :PreCountDir here----->
:PreCountDir [Strings to search, separated by space]
. . .
REM Code for PreCountDir
. . .

:ExitProc
. . .
REM Code for ExitProc
. . .
Exit
```