# powershell script to delete files based on start of file name

Tags: powershell, glob, get-childitem

So i have files in a folder that start with

```
1__
```

and

```
0__
```

example files

```
1__shal1absahal9182skab.php
0__abns1a3bshal54a4m5sb.php
```

i am trying to get my powershell script to only delete files of `1__` that are older than `60 mins` while `0__` can be deleted every `360 mins`.

here is my current code

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-360)
$path = "C:\cache"

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force

# Delete any empty directories left behind after deleting the old files.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

my script currently treats both files as the same and deletes them both on `360 minute` intivals.

Comment: It looks like a single user down-voted all answers without an explanation (though there's no way to know for sure).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a solution using if and else with some regex pattern matching.

```
$limit_guest = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-360) #6 hours
$limit_logged_in = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60) #1 hours
$path = "C:\cache"

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { if ( $_ -match "^0__.*" ) { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit_guest } else { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit_logged_in } } | Remove-Item -Force

# Delete any empty directories left behind after deleting the old files.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

You can streamline [your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59020117/45375) as follows:

- Use `-File` and `-Directory` to limit [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) to output only items of that type.
- Use `-Include` with a PowerShell [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) to limit matching to files whose names start with `0__` or `1__`.

```
$now = Get-Date
$limit_guest = $now.AddMinutes(-360) #6 hours
$limit_logged_in = $now.AddMinutes(-60) #1 hour

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $path -Recurse -Force -Include '[01]__*' | 
  Where-Object {
    $_.CreationTime -lt ($limit_guest, $limit_logged_in)[$_.Name -like '1__*']
  } | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf

# Delete any empty directories left behind after deleting the old files.
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $path -Recurse -Force |
  Where-Object { 
   (Get-ChildItem -File -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Recurse -Force).Count -eq 0
  } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- `($limit_guest, $limit_logged_in)[$_.Name -like '1__*']` emulates a ternary conditional by selecting one of the `$limit_*` values based on conditional `$_.Name -like '1__*'`: if the conditional evaluates to `$true`, it is interpreted as array index `1`, otherwise as `0`.
- The `-like` operator supports the same wildcard patterns as `Get-ChildItem`'s `-Include` parameter, but note that the latter's `-Filter` parameter - while faster - supports only different, less powerful patterns - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739503/45375).

Answer (score 0):

Please find the script for exact expected output.

Replace path with your original path

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\***\Desktop\New folder\*.php" -Recurse -Force

foreach($file in $folder) 
{ 

    if($file.Name -match "^0_.*" -and $file.CreationTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-360) )
    {
        Remove-item $file  -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Write-Host "Deleted"$file.Name
    }
    elseif($file.Name -match "^1_.*" -and $file.CreationTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60))
    {
        Remove-item $file -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Write-Host "Deleted"$file.Name
    }
    else 
    {
    Write-Host "No files found"
    }
}
```

Comment: The script is working fine in my system. Could you please explain where you are facing the issue. So, that I can correct for you