# Specifying *.xls filter in Get-ChildItem also returns *.xlsx results

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that contains both .xls, .xlsx and .xlsm files, and would like to filter just the .xls files.

Why is the following line not working as I'd expect it to? I see .xls, .xlsx and .xlsm results.

```
Get-ChildItem $(Get-Location) -Filter *.xls | ForEach-Object { $_.Extension }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **`-Filter` parameter's wildcard matching is *not* performed by PowerShell**, it is passed through to the filesystem provider and ultimately the Windows API.
The matching performed there is burdened with many legacy behaviors and quirks, including the one you saw:

- **In *Windows PowerShell***, **`-Filter *.xls` effectively behaves like `-Filter *.xls*`**. Therefore, `-Filter *.xls` matches both `foo.xls` and `foo.xlsx`, for instance; this happens, because **the 8.3 (short) file names are *also* being matched behind the scenes**; for instance, `foo.xlsx`'s 8.3 file name looks something like `FOO~1.XLS`; note the truncation (and capitalization) of `.xlsx` to `.XLS`.
- While the **short-name matching behavior no longer occurs in PowerShell [Core] v6+**, fortunately, **other legacy quirks persist**<sup>[1]</sup>, as does the most notable difference (which won't go away): **only *PowerShell* wildcard expressions** (see [`about_Wildcards`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)) **support character ranges / sets via `[...]`** (e.g., `[a-z]`) - they're not supported with `-Filter`.
- **Use of the `-Filter` parameter is in general still preferable** to `-Path` / `-Include` (see below) **due to its superior performance** (filtering happens *at the source*, instead of after the fact in PowerShell).

The **workaround is to use the `-Path` parameter** in order to use *PowerShell's* wildcard matching:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path (Get-Location) *.xls) | ForEach-Object { $_.Extension }

# Or, more simply
Get-ChildItem -Path $PWD/*.xls | ForEach-Object Extension
```

Note: **With `-Recurse` you'd use the `-Include` parameter instead**; *without* `-Recurse`, the behavior of `-Include` (and `-Exclude`) is *unintuitive*, unfortunately - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375).

---

**[1] Notable other quirks:**

- Multiple consecutive `?` wildcards can match names with *fewer* characters.

  - E.g., `Get-ChildItem -Filter ??.txt` matches `aa.txt` and unexpectedly also `a.txt`
- Pattern `*.` matches extension-less file and directory names.

  - E.g., `Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.` finds all files (`-File`) whose names do not have an extension (e.g., `file`); this quirk can actually be useful, in that it is the simplest and best-performing way to locate extension-less files (`-Path *.` does *not* work, because it looks for a file name *literally* ending in a `.`).
  - Note: This was *temporarily* changed in PowerShell Core 6.x (as of 6.2.3), but the behavior is back as of PowerShell Core 7.0.
- Conversely, `*.*` includes extension-less file and directory names as well.

See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739503/45375) by [Zenexer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188377/zenexer) for the backstory and the gory details.

Answer (score 0):

-filter matches the short version of the filename.  This has been covered elsewhere.  It's resolved in powershell 6.

```
echo hi > file.xlsx
dir -filter *.xls


    Directory: C:\users\js\foo


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/11/2020   9:54 AM              4 file.xlsx


cmd /c dir /x

 Volume in drive C is DISK
 Volume Serial Number is A11A-AA11

 Directory of C:\users\js\foo

02/11/2020  09:54 AM    <DIR>                       .
02/11/2020  09:54 AM    <DIR>                       ..
02/11/2020  09:54 AM                 4 FILE~1.XLS   file.xlsx
               1 File(s)              4 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   3,380,170,752 bytes free
```