# PowerShell, Get-ChildItem with -Depth output

Tags: powershell, recursion

I'm a bit confused by the `-Depth` flag for Get-ChildItem. The following works great (finds all files and folders only one deep under "C:\Program Files"):

```
dir 'C:\Program Files\' -Depth 1
```

But if I then want to extend it to find only *.txt type files, I cannot find how to do that (following just give weirdly unexpected output where `-Depth 1` is ignored and it instead does the equivalent of a `-Recurse` to *all* subfolders no matter how deep):

```
dir 'C:\Program Files\*.txt' -Depth 1
dir 'C:\Program Files\' -Include *.txt -Depth 1
dir 'C:\Program Files\*' -Include *.txt -Depth 1
```

How do we use `-Depth` to a specific depth for Get-ChildItem and a required file-pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue gets solved when you use `Filter` instead of `Include`. Filter parameter will return file in correct pattern with depth. (TESTED)

```
dir 'C:\Program Files\' -Filter *.txt  -Depth 1
```

Comment: An effective workaround; two things worth noting: in PowerShell [Core] 6+, the workaround is no longer needed, because the [underlying bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3726) has been fixed. `-Filter` is often preferable for performance anyway, but its behavior differs from PowerShell's own wildcard matching - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171419/45375).

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you're seeing is a ***bug* in *Windows PowerShell*, that has since been *fixed in PowerShell [Core] 6+*** - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3726).

<sup>Given that Windows PowerShell is no longer actively developed, it is unlikely that the bug will be fixed.</sup>

To spell it out, **Windows PowerShell *ignores* `-Depth`'s depth constraint in the following cases**:

- with `-Include` or `-Exclude`
- if the (implied) `-Path` argument contains wildcard characters.

While *recursion* is still performed, no depth limit is imposed; in effect, `-Depth` behaves like `-Recurse` (alone) in these cases.

**Workarounds**:

- For `-Include` and wildcard-based `-Path` arguments where the wildcards are limited to the *last* path component:

  - Use `-Filter` instead, as shown in [Wasif Hasan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60501784/45375).
  - **Caveat**: `-Filter` is usually preferable anyway for its superior performance, but its **wildcard language is *less powerful* than PowerShell's and has *legacy quirks*** - notably, character sets and ranges (`[...]`) are *not* supported and in Windows PowerShell a filter such as `*.xls` also matches `*.xlsx` files, for instance  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171419/45375).
- For `-Exclude`:

  - Use only `-Depth` and perform filtering after the fact with a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call; e.g., 
    `Get-ChildItem -File 'C:\Program Files\' -Depth 1 | Where-Object Name -NotLike *.txt`
- [Probably rarely needed] For wildcard-based `-Path` arguments with wildcard characters (also) in a component *other* than the last one (e.g., `C:\foo*\bar`)

  - Use `-Recurse` and perform filtering after the fact with `Where-Object`; in this case, you'll also have to weed out too-deep paths by counting the number of their components.

Comment: Good to know, thanks Michael. Yes, I could not get my head around how unintuitive this behaviour appeared. Would be nice if Microsoft did a bug-fix rollout for PS 5.1. We are going to be using PS 5.1 for a long time since it has so much Windows specific functionality that PS 6 and 7 just do not have. Hopefully at some point MS can recognise that. Don't need any 6/7 features backported to 5.1, but at least fixing bugs would be useful. (PS v5.1 SP1!)

Comment: Understood, @YorSubs; the upcoming v7.0 is an attempt to be a viable substitute for v5.1, but it'll never be able to offer _everything_ that Windows PowerShell does. It would indeed be nice if more fixes were back-ported, but chances are that only security-critical issues will be addressed. [UserVoice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell) is the official place for Windows PowerShell bug reports, but, unfortunately, most issues reported there seem to never get addressed.

Comment: On PS v7, `(Get-WMIObject win32_operatingsystem).name` results in `Get-WMIObject: The term 'Get-WMIObject' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`. If WMI is missing on PS v7, that's really a deal-breaker. Are there modules that re-add WMI for when running PS v7 on Windows, as otherwise I just cannot touch it for my work or personal projects? :-(

Comment: @YorSubs, here's the standard advice: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell _Core_, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: oh, I see, that's good then. I think I do vaguely remember hearing that a while back but I guess I never really kept on top of these things (if it works, it works!). Great thanks, I'lll try and convert everything that is WMI over to CIM then, hopefully not too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of PowerShell there was no depth, in that case the above can also be

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\DIRECTORY\*","C:\DIRECTORY\*\*"
```

If it is pure for filenames then

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\program files" -file -Depth 3 -Force -erroraction SilentlyContinue).FullName
```

Is identical to the ancient kind of tricks, i.e.

```
(cmd.exe /c dir "c:\program files" /b /a-d /s)|foreach {if ($_.split("\").length -le 5){$_}}
```

It's amazing that PowerShell is even faster than the above line! I remember that a few years ago that was not the case, but I just tested it and it was 3-4 times faster

Answer (score 0):

To further clarify the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60501414/1722792) by Wasif Hasan
As I was going through the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) for the Get-ChildItem, it is stated there

> When using the -Include parameter, if you do not include an asterisk
>   in the path the command returns no output.

Which means that the `Depth` will be ignored automatically as the behavior required for the `Include` is recursive. Further some details of the -Include reveals these points.

> If the Recurse parameter is added to the command, the trailing
>   asterisk (*) in the Path parameter is optional. The Recurse parameter
>   gets items from the Path directory and its subdirectories. For
>   example, -Path C:\Test\ -Recurse -Include *.txt

So the behavior you are looking for is in the `Filter` flag for the `Get-ChildItem` which do not requires any wild cards

For me the `Depth` flag with any other flag that accepts wild cards in the path do not make sense as the purpose of the `Depth` flag is to restrict the depth of search in the Items where as specifying a wild card excludes that particular purpose.
You can try this by simply using this command and you will see that the `Depth` parameter is not effective if you specify a wild card in the path for example

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\DIRECTORY\* -Depth 1
```

and

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\DIRECTORY\* -Depth 2
```

are going to return the same results.

Hope this helps clarify some issues

Comment: Yes thanks, I was just going to say also that this doesn't make sense. Give me an error, or a meaningful warning that indicates how my syntax might be wrong, don't give me strangely unexpected results. I see zero reasons why `Depth` could not be written such that it operates *as expected* in those other situations. All seems a bit counterproductive. I wonder what the author of this Cmdlet was thinking with this strange output result.

Comment: The behavior is a _bug_ in Windows PowerShell that has since been fixed in PowerShell [Core] 6+ - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3726). Yes, `-Filter` doesn't require the `-Path` argument to end in `*` to take effect, but neither does `-Include` _if recursion is also performed_, and the use of `-Depth` _implies_ `-Recurse`. It is the _bug_ that makes your two `C:\DIRECTORY\*` commands with differing depths output the same result - the `-Depth` limit is again ignored.

Comment: @mklement0 agreed about the reported issue but not sure why `-Include`'s official documentation states that it needs a wildcard in the path or will return empty

Comment: @DevX, that is due to an _unrelated issue_, namely the unfortunate fact that _without recursion_, the `-Include` pattern is (first) matched against the _input paths themselves_, which means that often _nothing_ matches. Appending `\*` to input paths works around that problem - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375). As written, your answer amounts to a distraction, because it adds to the confusion, so please consider amending it.