# Powershell - match with array

Tags: arrays, powershell, string-matching

i´m a beginner in Powershell, i have some scripts working. but now I´m stucked with this little problem.
I have this little script. I have a folder with some files $ORIGEN. I need to get all those name files that match with te values in the variable $ARCHIVOS, and put them in a new variable $DATA.
Can anyone tell me how i can make a match between the names in $ARCHIVOS with the files in the folder?. If i use only 1 value in the variable $ARCHIVOS, it works fine, but when i have an array y doesn´t match with anything. I tried many solutions, but nothing.
THanks in advance for some help. And sorry by my english

```
$ORIGEN= "C:\FILES\"
$ARCHIVOS='MLR*.384', 'MP0*.384'

 $data= Get-ChildItem $ORIGEN | Where-Object{$_.Name -match $ARCHIVOS}
 Write-Host $data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) (or, since you're not recursing, just [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item)) with `*` and `-Include`, which (unlike `-Filter`) accepts an *array* of wildcard patterns:<sup>[1]</sup>

```sh
Get-ChildItem -File $ORIGEN/* -Include $ARCHIVOS
```

- `-File` instructs `Get-ChildItem` to return matching *files* only (rather than also directories).
- The `/*` (`\*`) wildcard appended to the input path (`$ORIGEN`) is necessary, because `_Include` and `-Exclude`, in the absence of `-Recurse`, are only applied to the *input path(s) themselves*, not their *child* items.

  - This surprising behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #3304](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3304).

---

If you want **only the *names* of the matching files**, simply access the `.Name` property on the output from the `Get-ChildItem` call via `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), which, thanks to [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), returns the matching files' names as an array (assuming there's at least two):

```sh
$fileNames = (Get-ChildItem -File $ORIGEN/* -Include $ARCHIVOS).Name
```

---

As for **what you tried**, `$_.Name -match $ARCHIVOS`:

- The [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) operator operates on [regular expressions (regexes)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), not on [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), yet your `$ARCHIVOS` array contains *wildcard* expressions.
- Additionally, `-match` doesn't (meaningfully) accept an *array* of regexes on the RHS.
- If you did want to solve this problem with `-match` (which isn't necessary, given the shorter and more efficient solution shown at the top), you'd have to create a *single* regex that uses *alternation* (`|`):

  ```sh
  # Note how the individual patterns are now expressed as *regexes*
  # and are *anchored* with ^ and $ to ensure that the *entire name* matches.
  # By default, -match finds *substrings*.
  $_.Name -match ('^MLR.*\.384$', '^MP0.*\.384$' -join '|')
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Additionally, `-Filter` - which with a *single* pattern is generally preferable to `-Include` for *performance* reasons - doesn't use *PowerShell*'s wildcard language, but delegates matching to the host platform's file-system APIs. This means that range or character-set expressions such as `[0-9]` and `[fg]` are *not* supported, and, on Windows, several *legacy quirks* affect the matching behavior - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171419/45375) for more information.</sup>