# Using powershell to merge PDFs in multiple subfolders with pdftk and then delete original PDF files

Tags: powershell, pdf, pdftk

I have a root folder that contains many subfolders, each with multiple PDFs.
I then have a powershell script that goes through the folder structure and creates a merged PDF file (using PDFtk) for each subfolder as follows:

[image]

```
    $pdftk = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"
    $RootFolder = "path to root folder"
    Get-ChildItem -r -include *.pdf | group DirectoryName | % {& $PDFtk $_.group CAT OUTPUT "$($_.Name | Split-Path -Parent)\$($_.Name | Split-Path -Leaf)_merged.pdf"}
```

The script works as required, however I will be working with a very large amount of data, and for that reason I need to delete the original PDFs from each folder after the merge is completed.

Basically, i need the script to look in the first folder 4830_2017, create the merged file 4830_2017_merged.pdf and then delete the PDFs located inside the 4830_2017 folder before moving on to the next folder, and doing the same thing.

I am stuggling to find the correct way of deleting the contents of each folder after the merge.

Thanks is advance for your help.

Comment: Besides your problem, I recommend `pswritepdf` for merging pdfs instead of `pdftk` in powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) script block, `$_.Group` contains each group's, i.e. each directory's [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances representing the `*.pdf` files, so you can pipe them to [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) after a successful merge:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.pdf) | 
  Group-Object DirectoryName | 
    ForEach-Object {
      & $PDFtk $_.Group.FullName CAT OUTPUT "$($_.Name | Split-Path -Parent)\$($_.Name | Split-Path -Leaf)_merged.pdf"
      if (0 -eq $LASTEXITCODE) { # If the merge succeeded.
        $_.Group | Remove-Item   # Delete.
      }
    }
```

Note:

- The [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) command is enclosed in `(...)` so as to ensure that its output is collected in full before further processing, to rule out side effects from new `*.pdf` files getting created or old ones getting deleted affecting the recursive enumeration.

  - `-Filter *.pdf` is used in lieu of `-Include *.pdf`, which is functionally equivalent in this case, but performs much better, due to delegating the filtering to the file-system APIs rather, at the source - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171419/45375).
- `& $PDFtk $_.Group` was changed to `& $PDFtk $_.Group.FullName` to ensure that *full* file paths are passed; note that this is no longer necessary in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, where [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) and [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances *consistently* stringify to their full paths - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375).
- [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) outputs [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo) instances.