# Powershell glob pattern matching

Tags: windows, powershell, glob

I am looking through `C:\ProgramFiles` for a jar file named `log4j-core-x.y.z.jar`. I am trying to match on the last digit `z`, which can be both a one or two digit number (0-99). I can't seem to get the right glob pattern to accomplish this.

`Code:`

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files\' -Filter log4j-core-*.*.[1-9][0-9].jar -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | %{$_.FullName}
```

This yields no results, but when I just do all wildcards like, `-Filter log4j-core-*.*.*.jar`, I get:

```
C:\Program Files\apache-log4j-2.16.0-bin\apache-log4j-2.16.0-bin\log4j-core-2.16.0-javadoc.jar
C:\Program Files\apache-log4j-2.16.0-bin\apache-log4j-2.16.0-bin\log4j-core-2.16.0-sources.jar
C:\Program Files\apache-log4j-2.16.0-bin\apache-log4j-2.16.0-bin\log4j-core-2.16.0-tests.jar
C:\Program Files\apache-log4j-2.16.0-bin\apache-log4j-2.16.0-bin\log4j-core-2.16.0.jar
```

The only thing I care about getting is `C:\Program Files\apache-log4j-2.16.0-bin\apache-log4j-2.16.0-bin\log4j-core-2.16.0.jar`, `log4j-core-2.16.0.jar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-Filter` doesn't support filtering with *regex* or [Character ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2#character-ranges) such as `[A-Z]` or `[0-9]`. Thanks [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355772/powershell-glob-pattern-matching/70356061?noredirect=1#comment124370165_70356061) for pointing it out.

From the parameter description of [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2) official documentation:

> The filter string is passed to the .NET API to enumerate files. The API only supports `*` and `?` wildcards.

Try with this:

```
$getChildItemSplat = @{
    Path        = 'C:\Program Files\'
    Filter      = 'log4j-core-*.*.??.jar'
    Recurse     = $true
    ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
    Force       = $true
}

Get-ChildItem @getChildItemSplat |
    # Ends with a . followed by 1 or 2 digits and the .jar extension
    Where-Object Name -Match '\.\d{1,2}\.jar$'
```

Answer (score 3):

[Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70356061/45375) offers a **[regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-assisted solution** that has the potential to perform much more sophisticated matching than required in the case at hand.

Let me complement it with a **[wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)-based solution** that builds on your own attempt:

- The `-Filter` parameter does *not* support *PowerShell*'s wildcard syntax; it only supports `*` and `?` as wildcard metacharacters (as Santiago notes), *not* also character-range/set constructs such as `[0-9]`.

  - Instead, `-Filter` arguments are interpreted by the platform's file-system APIs, which on Windows additionally have legacy quirks - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171419/45375).
  - That said, with patterns that `-Filter` does support, its use is preferable  to `-Include` (see below), because it performs much better, due to filtering *at the source*.
- By contrast, the `-Include` parameter *does* use PowerShell's wildcards and additionally supports *multiple* patterns.

Unlike regexes, character-range/set expressions in PowerShell's wildcard language do *not* support *duplication* (quantifier) logic and match *exactly one character* each (just like `?` does for *any* single character; `*` is the only metacharacter that *implicitly* supports duplication: zero or more characters).

Therefore, `[1-9][0-9]` matches exactly 2 characters (digits), and *also* matching just *one* digit (`[0-9]`) requires an *additional* pattern:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'C:\Program Files' -Include log4j-core-*.*.[0-9].jar, log4j-core-*.*.[1-9][0-9].jar -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | 
  ForEach-Object FullName
```

**Caveats**:

- Using `-Include` (or `-Exclude`) *without `-Recurse`* doesn't work as one would expect - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375).
- As of PowerShell 7.2, combining `-Recurse` with `-Include` suffers from performance problems due to inefficient implementation - see [GitHub issue #8662](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8662).