# Get path based on regex Powershell

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, glob

I queried the registry to get a file path I am looking for. However, I need to go one directory lower to retrieve some file info I need. The pattern I am trying to match against is `Officexx` or `OFFICExx`. I can't seem to get the path I need.

Found path from registry: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office`

What I need is: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Officexx`

Code:

```
$base_install_path = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office";
$full_install_path = $base_install_path+'\Office[\d+.*]'
Write-Output $full_install_path;
```

This returns:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office[\d+.*]
```

Desired output:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15
```

Not this could be any two digit # ^^

Comment: `$base_install_path+'\Office[\d+.*]'` is a string concatenation, have you tried searching the path with `Get-ChildItem` ? That should be part of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on [Santiago Squarzon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) helpful comment:

```sh
# Find all child directories matching the given wildcard pattern, if any.
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "$base_install_path\Office[0-9][0-9]*"
```

- Unlike POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, PowerShell does *not* support automatic globbing of unquoted strings (pattern matching against file names, known as [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)) and instead requires explicit use of the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) or [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) cmdlets; e.g., the equivalent of `bash` command `pattern='*.txt'; echo $pattern` in PowerShell is `$pattern='*.txt'; Get-ChildItem -Path $pattern`

  - Note that *objects* describing the matching files or directories are output by these cmdlets; use their *properties* as needed, e.g. `(Get-ChildItem $pattern).Name` or `(Get-ChildItem $pattern).FullName` (full path). Use `Get-ChildItem $pattern | Get-Member -Type Properties` to see all available properties.
- The `-Path` parameter of these cmdlets expects a PowerShell [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) to perform the desired matching, and the expression in the command at the top matches *exactly two* digits (`[0-9][0-9]`), followed by *zero or more* characters (`*`), whatever they may be (potentially including additional digits).

  - Note: Only *PowerShell*'s wildcard language - as accepted by the `-Path` and `-Include` / `-Exclude` parameters (and in many other contexts) - supports character *ranges* (e.g. `[0-9]` to match any decimal digit) and *sets* (e.g. `[._]` to match either `.` or `_`). By contrast, `Get-ChildItem`'s `-Filter` parameter uses the wildcard language of the *file-system APIs* (as `cmd.exe` does), which does *not* support them, and additionally exhibits legacy quirks  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171419/45375) for more information.
  - While PowerShell's wildcard character ranges and sets fundamentally work the same as in regexes (regular expressions, see below), regex-specific escape sequences such as `\d` are *not* supported, and you generally cannot *quantify* them; that is, something like `[0-9]` only ever matches *exactly one* digit.

---

Given that wildcard patterns support only *one*, non-specific *duplication construct*, namely the aforementioned `*`, matching a *specific range* of digits - such as 1 or 2 *at most* or a *specific count* - such as *exactly two* - requires post-filtering based on a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) (which is what you tried to use):

```sh
# Find all child directories matching the given regex, if any.
# Matches 'Office' at the start of the name (^),
# followed by 1 or 2 ({1,2}) digits (\d), 
# followed by at least non-digit (\D), if any (?)
Get-ChildItem -Directory -LiteralPath $base_install_path |
  Where-Object Name -match '^Office\d{1,2}\D?'
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `[\d+.*]` is a *regex*, but you probably meant `\d+.*`, i.e. one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`) followed by zero more (`*`) characters, whatever they may be (`.`)
- Inside a character-range/set expression (`[...]`), `+`, `.` and `*` are used *verbatim*, i.e. they are *not* metacharacters and match *literal* `.` and `*` characters.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation. I thought there were only two (2) expression types: 1) "wildcard" (cmd '*', '.', and '?') and 2) "regex". It now appears there are three (3) types: 1) "wildcard" (cmd), 2) "PSWildcard" (adding explicit character ranges), and 3) "regex". Would you say that is a correct view?

Comment: @lit, yes - you can think of it as two wildcard "dialects", with the PowerShell one having more features and not being subject to legacy behavior. Also, the PowerShell dialect is used pervasively throughout PowerShell, not just in the context of the file-system. Many `-Name` parameters support wildcards; for instance, `Get-Process -Name ba*` finds all processes whose names start with `ba`. One downside with respect to file-system use is that `[` and `]` are legitimate characters in file names, requiring you to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter explicitly to match them _verbatim_.

Comment: Based on this, I wonder if a terminology distinction should be made. The output of `help Get-Process -Parameter Name` mentions "wildcard characters." However, it is not clear if this is traditional `cmd` wildcard characters or PSWildcard.

Comment: @lit, the only context in which the file-system wildcard dialect is spoken is the `-Filter` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp#parameters) currently state, "The filter string is passed to the .NET API to enumerate files. The API only supports `*` and `?` wildcards." (This lacks details, but conveys the most important distinction). In other words: wildcards in any other context refer to the PowerShell dialect.

Comment: This works, but how would I get it to print just the directory, like so: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Officexx`

Comment: @cynicalswan77, you mean you just want the full path _strings_? `Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "$base_install_path\Office[0-9][0-9]*" | ForEach-Object FullName` or, as an expression: `(Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "$base_install_path\Office[0-9][0-9]*").FullName`

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\' -Directory | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'Office\d+' }
```

---

In your regex, `[]` is a character class which means `[\d+.*]` is not "one or more numbers" it's "a backslash OR d OR plus OR dot OR asterisk".

```
PS C:\> "d+\" -match "[\d+]"
True
```

Not what you were looking for.

Comment: Good point re character class, but note that escape sequence `\d` _is_ recognized as such - try `'1' -match '[\d]'`