# Mass Conversion of (macintosh) .csv to (ms-dos) .csv

Tags: excel, windows, macos, powershell, csv

I am using a program to export hundreds of rows in an Excel sheet into separate documents, but the problem is that a PLC will be reading the files and they only save in (macintosh).csv with no option for windows. Is there a way to bulk convert multiple files with different names into the correct format?

I have used this code for a single file but I do not have the knowledge to use it for multiple in a directory

```
$path = 'c:\filename.csv';
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($path.Remove($path.Length-3)+'txt',[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($path).Replace("`n","`r`n"));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The ***general* PowerShell idiom for processing multiple files** one by one:

- Use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) (or [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item)) to enumerate the files of interest, as [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances.
- Pipe the result to a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call, whose [script-block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) argument (`{ ... }`) is invoked once for each input object received via the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines), reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).

***Specifically*, since you're calling .NET API methods, be sure to pass *full, file-system-native* file paths to them**, because .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's. **`$_.FullName`** does that.

Therefore:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath C:\ -Filter *.csv |
  ForEach-Object {
    [IO.File]::WriteAllText(
      [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.FullName, 'txt'),
      [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName).Replace("`n", "`r`n")
    )
  }
```

Note:

- In PowerShell *type literals* such as `[System.IO.File]`, the `System.` part is optional and can be omitted, as shown above.
- [`[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension), as used above, is a more robust way to obtain a copy of a path with the original file-name extension changed to a given one.
- While `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\*.csv` or even `Get-ChildItem C:\*.csv` would work too (`Get-ChildItem`'s first *positional* parameter is `-Path`), `-Filter`, as shown above, is usually preferable for performance reasons.

  - *Caveat*: While `-Filter` is typically sufficient, it  does *not* use *PowerShell*'s [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) language, but delegates matching to the host platform's file-system APIs. This means that range or character-set expressions such as `[0-9]` and `[fg]` are *not* supported, and, on Windows, several *legacy quirks* affect the matching behavior - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171419/45375) for more information.