# Create simple wildcard / filter pattern based on regex

Tags: .net, regex, powershell, filtering

### Context

When performing filter operations it's generally best to push the filter as far upstream as possible to get good performance; e.g. if I were using PowerShell to get all files from a directory `Get-ChildItem 'c:\temp\' -Filter '*.txt'` would be preferable to `Get-ChildItem 'c:\temp\' | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*.txt'}`.

However, in some situations the upstream component doesn't give us an option to push things upstream; e.g. if we wanted to find any image file we'd either have to make multiple calls to `Get-ChildItem` passing different values to `Filter` for each type, but resulting in traversing the directory multiple times and potentially returning the same files (if they match multiple filters); or we have to perform the filtering downstream.

If I were searching for image files (for this specifc example, lets say that's: `'*.png', '*.gif', '*.jpg', '*.jpeg'`) one approach may be to send `'*.*g*'` as the filter to the provider, so we elimiate a lot of candidates early on, then filter for the specific extensions we're interested in downstream.

### Question

Is there a known method for extracting a "like pattern/mask" which represents the partial implementation of a regex?

e.g. so I could implement something like this:

```
Function Get-ImageFiles {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$LiteralPath
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Pattern = '\.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$'
    )
    $simpleMask = ConvertTo-SimpleMask -RegexPattern $Pattern
    [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($LiteralPath, $simpleMask) |
        Select-String -Pattern $Pattern -Raw
}

# for '\.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$'      simpleMask would be '*.*g*'
# for '\.(?:jpg|jpeg)$'              simpleMask would be '*.jp*g'
# for '\.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg|webp)$' simpleMask would be '*.*'
```

Note: In this question I've used PowerShell for my example code; but I'm interested in any solution to this "regex to simple filter" problem.  This is more a question of curiosity than specific to the above example use case.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't convert an arbitrary regex pattern to a wildcard pattern - as wildcard patterns are essentially a *subset* of regex.

If performance is your chief concern, enumerate all files and filter based on the `Extension` attribute - that way you won't need any variable-length matching capabilities at all, and the comparison will be much faster than any regex or wildcard comparison:

```
Get-ChildItem -File |Where-Object Extension -in '.png','.gif','.jpg','.jpeg'
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76738504/45375):

> if we wanted to find any image file we'd either have to make multiple calls to `Get-ChildItem`, passing different values to Filter for each type

The `-Include` parameter allows you to pass *multiple* patterns and therefore requires only *one* [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call.

However:

- Unlike `-Filter`, `-Include` does *not* filter *at the source* and requires the cmdlet to enumerate *all* items and itself match them against  the specified patterns.
- Unless you use `-Recurse`, you'll have to end your input path in `*` to make `-Include` work as intended - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375) for details.
- Note: that the wildcard "dialects" supported by `-Filter` vs. `-Include` (and `-Exclude` and `-Path`) differ: `-Filter` uses the wildcard patterns of the underlying file-system APIs, which are both less powerful than PowerShell's [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) and have many legacy quirks - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171419/45375) for details.

Therefore, for instance:

```bash
# Note the trailing * in the (positionally implied) -Path argument,
# to make -Include work as intended.
# This isn't necessary if -Recurse is also used.
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\* -Include *.png, *.gif, *.jpg, *.jpeg
```

---

To improve performance you can actually *combine* a `-Filter` argument with `-Include`, which means that you'll get *fast preliminary filtering with `-Filter`*, but with *false positives*, which the `-Include` patterns then eliminate:

```bash
# Note the use of *both* -Filter and -Include
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\* -Filter *.*g* -Include *.png, *.gif, *.jpg, *.jpeg
```

Note that a pattern such as `*.*g*` doesn't limit matching of the `*g*` part to the *extension*, and also matches file names such as `f.g.txt` or `f._g.txt`