# copy certain files to another folder

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to copy files from one folder/sub folder to a new folder. below is a picture of what I need to do.

[image]

I need to copy all the files that exist on the D:\ drive and sub folders inside the d:\ drive and that has the file name that starts with first five numeric characters to another folder called Test2. so in the above image, I need to copy all the files that you can see in the image and all the files that exist inside "Test" folder and that has the file name that starts with first five numeric characters to "test2" folder. Below is the image of Test folder:

[image]

Above image is just an example. I have hundreds of files on D:\ drive and hundreds of sub folders that has files whose file name starts with numeric character. I am only looking for first 5 characters. If the first five characters are numeric then it is safe to transfer the file to "Test2" folder. All the files are not necessary .pdf file, some are "jpg","tif" some are "txt" . Below is what I tried to do:

```
FOR %F IN (D:\SourceFolder\12345*.*) DO COPY "%F" D:\Test1\
```

The above line is only copying all the files from one sub folder. I want to copy all the  files from all the sub folders to the new folder. These sub folders have different names. While copying if the names are same so for e.g if the file in D:\ folder has the name "12345.jog" and there is already one file in Test2 folder that has name "12345.jpg" then I want to overwrite that file.

I tried to run this script in powershell ISE and nothing happened. Please see below screen shot:

[image]

and below is my folder structure:

[image]

this is inside "Test" and "Test100" folder:

[image]

[image]

this is the destination folder:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Mklement0, I updated my question. Basically, I want to overwrite the existing file in the event of name collision

Comment: this has more flexibility to do what you want:  xcopy /?

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *PowerShell* solution, using [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -LiteralPath D:\SourceFolder -Include [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.* |
  Copy-Item -Destination D:\Test1\ -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [**`-WhatIf`** common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above ***previews* the operation**. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

`[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.*` is a PowerShell [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expression that matches any name starting with 5 digits that has a non-empty filename extension, as supported by `-Include` (and by `-Exclude`, but *not* by `-Filter`, which - while usually preferable for performance reasons - only supports `*` and `?` as wildcard characters, with historical quirks - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171419/45375)).

As requested: In the event of name collisions, it is the *last* file with a given name encountered during traversal of the input directory tree that "wins".

Note that `-LiteralPath` (like the [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)-based `-Path` parameter) accepts an *array* of paths, so you can process *multiple* source directory trees with something like
`-LiteralPath D:\SourceFolder1, D:\SourceFolder2`
By contrast, if you pass *no* `-LiteralPath` (or `-Path`) argument, the *current* directory is targeted by default.

Comment: Do I need to specify SourceFolder every time. I have several sub folders. Do I need to run this command by changing the  SourceFolder. Is there any way, that it reads all the source folders in the above command.

Comment: @rimi, you can pass multiple paths to `-LiteralPath`- please see my update.

Comment: not sure what am I doing wrong, but nothing happen when I run the script that you mentioned above. I edited my questions with the screen shots when I run the script along with the folder structure.

Comment: @rimi, the only explanation I can think of is that your source folders do not contain matching files - assuming that no files are actually copied. Note that `Copy-Item` produces _no_ visible output by default, except with `-Verbose` (or, as a _preview_, with `-WhatIf`).

Comment: @rimi, also, your updated screenshot doesn't show what's _inside_ the destination folder, and the only eligible source file it shows are _outside_ the source folders.

Comment: Hi Mklement0, I edited my question with additional screen shots. when I run the command, nothing is happening. It's not even copying the files from outside the folder to Test1 folder. I tried to run powershell script from command prompt then also nothing happened. My destination folder is totally empty.

Comment: @rimi, it wasn't obvious that you needed more _abstract_ matching, based on the first 5 chars. being a digit, whatever its value - please see my update, which now uses `-Include` with a (PowerShell-specific) wildcard pattern. Of course, any files located _outside_ the folders targeted with `-LiteralPath` will _not_ be copied.

Comment: Hi Mklement0,  It worked! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hi Mklement0,, when I did this command, I am getting an error:  Missing an argument for parameter 'LiteralPath'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String[]' and try again. when I omitted -LiteralPath, I get an error saying 
Copy-Item : Cannot overwrite the item D:\Test1\5555555.pdf with itself.
At D:\Ram.ps1:2 char:3

Comment: @rimi, the first attempt suggests that you didn't follow `-LiteralPath` with actual paths. The second attempt suggests that you ran your command from ``D:\``, which cannot work (except with additional, nontrivial effort).