# PowerShell ISE and VS code provide different output with the same code for object selection

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, directory, filtering

Running the following command line in both PowerShell ISE and VS Code on my system:

```
Get-ChildItem "$($env:systemdrive)\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\" -Directory | Where { $_ -match "10." }
```

It gives out different output. On VS Code, the output will be like:

```
    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----           1/27/2023 12:50 PM                10.0.14393.0
d----           1/27/2023 12:50 PM                10.0.15063.0
d----           1/27/2023 12:50 PM                10.0.16299.0
d----           1/27/2023 12:50 PM                10.0.17134.0
d----           10/7/2021  4:57 PM                10.0.18362.0
d----           10/7/2021  4:54 PM                10.0.19041.0
d----           1/11/2022  5:14 PM                10.0.20348.0
d----           1/27/2023 12:50 PM                10.0.22621.0
d----           1/27/2023 12:50 PM                arm
d----           1/27/2023 12:50 PM                arm64
d----           1/27/2023 12:50 PM                x64
d----           1/27/2023 12:50 PM                x86
```

Yet in the ISE, the output will be like:

```
    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                      
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                      
d-----        1/27/2023  12:50 PM                10.0.14393.0                                                                              
d-----        1/27/2023  12:50 PM                10.0.15063.0                                                                              
d-----        1/27/2023  12:50 PM                10.0.16299.0                                                                              
d-----        1/27/2023  12:50 PM                10.0.17134.0                                                                              
d-----        10/7/2021   4:57 PM                10.0.18362.0                                                                              
d-----        10/7/2021   4:54 PM                10.0.19041.0                                                                              
d-----        1/11/2022   5:14 PM                10.0.20348.0                                                                              
d-----        1/27/2023  12:50 PM                10.0.22621.0
```

To me, this is a bug with PowerShell within VS code, or PowerShell 7, since I have the PSVersion 7.3.3 for VS code, and PSVersion 5.1.17763.3770 for ISE.

Anybody have any thought?

Comment: This is due to a change in behavior between Windows PowerShell 5.1 (the version used by ISE) in which "stringifying" a file system object outputs its name, whereas in PowerShell 7.x (the version underpinning VSCode) this results in the full path. Run `Get-ChildItem |% { "$_" }` in both to see this. Change your code to `Where-Object { $_.Name -match ... }` in any case

Comment: Reason is, with PowerShell 7, a `DirectoryInfo` instance when converted to string would resolve to its `FullName` property and your path happens to be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin` and `"10."` matches this pattern so every child item is listed. As opposed, `DirectoryInfo` instances when coerced to string will display their `Name` property in PowerShell 5.1. If you want accurate results in both versions you should: `| Where { $_.Name -match "10\." }`

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 6+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the helpful comments:

**tl;dr**

To be safe, *always*:

- refer to the ***name*** of a **directory- or file-information object** output by `Get-ChildItem` explicitly with **`.Name`**
- similarly, to get the **full (absolute) *path***, use **`.FullName`**

The same applies analogously to the `.Parent` property of a directory-info object, which is itself a directory-info object.
By contrast, to get a file-info object's parent directory's name, use `.Directory.Name`, and `.DirectoryName` for the full path.

In your case:

```bash
Get-ChildItem "$($env:systemdrive)\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin" -Directory | 
  Where { $_.Name -match '^10\.' } # Note the use of .Name
```

Note that I've changed to `10.` to `^10\.`: Because the `-match` operator uses [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), you must escape a *literal* `.` character that you want matched as such as `\.`
Additionally, it's better to ensure that literal `10.` only match at the *start* of a directory name, hence the use use of `^`.

That said, you can simplify and speed up your command with passing a *wildcard* pattern to [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)'s `-Filter` parameter:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter 10.* "$($env:systemdrive)\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\" -Directory
```

---

##### Background information

There is ***no* bug**, just a ***change in behavior* between .NET Framework** - which Windows PowerShell (the legacy edition with versions up to v5.1) is built on - **and .NET (Core) 5+** - which [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) is built on - with respect to **how [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) and
[`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances**, as output by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem),  **stringify** (are coerced to strings).

- In **Windows PowerShell**, they ***situationally* stringify by their `.Name` property only**, *depending on the specifics of the `Get-ChildItem` command that emitted them*; at other times they stringify by their `.FullName` property.

  - See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375) for the conditions under which this name-only stringification happens.
- In **PowerShell (Core)** they ***always* stringify by their `.FullName` property**, i.e. by their full (absolute) *path*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `$_ -match '10.'` causes each input directory-info object (`$_`) to be *stringified*, due to `-match` being a string-only operator.
- Therefore, in PowerShell (Core) `$_` became a *full path*, and the full paths of *all* your input directories match regex `10.`, given that `.` can match _any character; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # -> $true, because regex '10.' matches substring '10\' in the path
  'C:\...\10\bin\arm' -match '10.'
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Note that it is the *file-system*'s wildcard language that `-Filter` supports, which differs from *PowerShell*'s [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) in that it has fewer features and legacy quirks - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739503/45375) for the gory details.</sup>