# is get-childItem's new -file parameter fast like -filter or slow like -include?

Tags: powershell, filter, powershell-3.0, get-childitem

***EDIT** Hoping here to clarify my convoluted and misleading question... based on my mistaken assumption that -file accepts inputs. Thanks for setting me straight and pointing out that it's just a switch parameter; the inputs in my example actually get passed to -path. Sounds like that may be the fastest purely powershell way to search for multiple file types, since -filter accepts only a single input and -include is slower.*

The get-childItem [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) says "Filters are more efficient than other parameters, because the provider applies them when retrieving the objects, rather than having Windows PowerShell filter the objects after they are retrieved."

v3 has a [new parameter set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847897.aspx) with a -file parameter, probably meant for excluding directories, to match cmd.exe's `dir /a:-d`

Like -include and unlike -filter, -file accepts multiple, as in `gci -file "*.ldf","*.bak"`

So i'm wondering, and have thus far failed to reliably test, if -file is like -filter from a performance perspective, ie "more efficient", or more like the "other parameters" like -include. If -file is a filter, that's nice because afaict -filter only handles one filter at a time, so if you want multiple filters (like *.ldf and *.bak) then you need to either run `gci -filter` twice or use -include instead. So I'm wondering if -file lets us reap the efficiency benefits of a filter, for multiple filters.

I stumbled on some error text that's got me optimistic. The -file parameter wants -path to be the current directory, so this `gci -path $path -file "*.bak","*.ldf"` gives an error. Push-location seems like a viable workaround, but here I'm more interested in the content of the error text:

*Get-ChildItem : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Filter'. Specified method is not supported.*

I called -file but the error complains about "parameter 'Filter'". So maybe -file is efficient like a filter? OTOH, -filter doesn't need -path to be the current directory, so in that respect -file is more like -include.

Comment: I can tell you that -file (and -Directory) is considerably faster than -Include or ?{$_.PsIsContainer}

Comment: In my anecdotal testing at least, -File is faster than -Filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just one precision:

```
gci -path $path -file "*.bak","*.ldf"
```

`-file` is a `switch parameter` (as `-directory` is) and doesn't accept values (To get only files, use the File parameter and omit the Directory parameter. To exclude files, use the Directory parameter and omit the File parameter); then the `"*.bak","*.ldf"` are implicitly passed to `-filter` as value, and `filter` accept only `string` and not `string[]`. That's where your error came from.

Regarding performance: using `-file` or `-directory` is faster than using a `where-object psiscontainer` or  `? { !$_.psiscontainer}` because it's done at provider (filesystem in this case) level.

Comment: Another way to list only directory is `dir -attributes d`; to list only files is `dir -attributes !d`. Or filter for any other file attributes and any combinations of them.

Comment: Thanks, that's good news. If -file inputs are implicitly passed to -filter, then -file should indeed offer the performance benefit of a filter, for multiple filters... whereas when calling -filter directly, we were limited to a single filter input (*.ldf or *.bak but not both).

Comment: @noam the benefit it's only to exclude directory in this specific case. In other case  "*.bak","*.ldf" is assigned to the first parameter that accept string[]

Comment: so this: `gci -file "*.ldf","*.bak"` is equivalent to this `gci -file -path "*.ldf","*.bak"` ?

Comment: @noam the difference is that is there are folder with name ending with .ldf or .bak with -file param are excluded. follow you??

Comment: Yeah, thx for bearing with me. Now I see that -file is just a switch parameter. So it sounds like the most efficient (purely powershell) way to search for both bak and ldf files would be to use `-path "*.ldf","*.bak"` from the current directory. Or am I missing a better way?

Comment: @noam IMAO it is. adding `-file` some better performance because folder are skipped. For finding files in deep folder recursion by command line the best is using `cmd.exe /c dir *.ldf,*.bak /s` and eventually parse the result in powershell to cast returned value to `[fileinfo]`, but it's just an opinion!

Comment: @noam in v3 `get-chiditem -path *.ldf,*.bak -r -File` it's the best for deep folder search IMO.